# CDF of distribution $A+B$

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

I have two independent continuous random variables, $A$ and $B$. I want to find the cumulative distribution function of $A+B$.

$A$ is log-logistically distributed, and $B$ is normally distributed.

How can I go about finding the CDF of $A+B$?

Comment: $A+B$ is not the _joint_ distribution of anything, and the _random variable_ $A+B$ does not have a joint distribution; it is a univariate random variable. To calculate the CDF of $A+B$, use $$F_{A+B}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_A(a)F_B(z-a)\,\mathrm da.$$

Comment: Please clarify if you want the distribution of the sum or the joint distribution.

Comment: If you need a general algebraic form, Dilip's approach is they thing to try (it's not always doable). If you just need it in one particular instance, there's always numerical convolution.

Comment: (ctd) ... More information would help narrow down possible answers.

Comment: @Glen_b It appears Dilip's approach isn't viable, so I'm doing numerical convolution. I have two arrays of the respective CDFs, I'm struggling to work out exactly how to convolve them. I can't use libraries (for technical reasons; this isn't homework), I know it's pretty simple but is there an example online so I can check I'm doing the right thing?

Comment: (When you say you can't use libraries, what exactly do you mean?) One way to do numerical convolution is to use fast Fourier transforms on a discretized version of the densities (essentially to round them to a discrete distribution, where the discretization is fine compared to the level of detail you need; for example in some applications, rounding money  amounts to whole dollars is more than adequate and then perform Fourier transforms numerically, take the product and then transform back). It's generally a good deal faster than the naive approach to convolution... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... Simulation is an alternative; it's a lot easier to do but not as 'smooth'. Sometimes one approach is better for some kinds of problems, and the other is better on other kinds of problems.

Comment: Of course, numerical convolution will give you a (discretized) pdf, so you'd need to integrate - or rather sum - it to get a cdf, and in the case of simulation you have a sample, so you have to approximate the cdf from that sample.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm implementing this in code – the "no libraries" restriction means I have to implement almost all of the logic and math myself. Thanks very much for your help by the way, I'm going to look into what you've said and get back.

Comment: Okay. That's likely to be quite a task, then.

Comment: Have a look at this related question:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45267/logistic-input-with-gaussian-noise